# Actionscript 3: Adding buttons/textfields to an instance of a class

Tags: actionscript-3, for-loop, dictionary, package

This absolutely does not work. The for loop simply spam tracing of one of the objects in the dictionary. After like 10 seconds i get this error message:

Error: Error #1502: A script has executed for longer than the default timeout period of 15 seconds.

Does anyone know why?

```
package 
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.utils.Dictionary;
import flash.display.Sprite;

public class Main extends MovieClip
{
    public static var bg_width = 980;
    public static var bg_height = 541;

    public var S_Norway:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
    public var S_Australia:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
    public var S_China:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
    public var S_South_Africa:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
    public var S_Brazil:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
    public var S_USA:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
    public var S_France:Dictionary = new Dictionary();

    // ------------------------------------------------------

    public static var airportDict:Dictionary = new Dictionary();


    public function Main()
    {
        S_USA["x"] = -299;
        S_USA["y"] = -114;
        S_USA["city"] = "New York";
        S_Norway["x"] = -60;
        S_Norway["y"] = -183;
        S_Norway["city"] = "Oslo";
        S_South_Africa["x"] = -26;
        S_South_Africa["y"] = 146;
        S_South_Africa["city"] = "Cape Town";
        S_Brazil["x"] = -210;
        S_Brazil["y"] = 73;
        S_Brazil["city"] = "Rio de Janeiro";
        S_France["x"] = -79;
        S_France["y"] = -135;
        S_France["city"] = "Paris";
        S_China["x"] = 239;
        S_China["y"] = -98;
        S_China["city"] = "Beijing";
        S_Australia["x"] = 307;
        S_Australia["y"] = 153;
        S_Australia["city"] = "Sydney";

        airportDict["USA"] = S_USA;
        airportDict["Norway"] = S_Norway;
        airportDict["South Africa"] = S_South_Africa;
        airportDict["Brazil"] = S_Brazil;
        airportDict["France"] = S_France;
        airportDict["China"] = S_China;
        airportDict["Australia"] = S_Australia;
        for (var k:Object in airportDict)
        {
            var value = airportDict[k];
            var key = k;
            trace(key);
            var airport:flyplass = new flyplass(key,airportDict[key]["bynavn"]);
            airport.coordinates(airportDict[key]["x"], airportDict[key]["y"]);
            this.addChild(airport);
        }
```

---

Running script in debug mode (CTRL - SHIFT - Enter) produced the following output.

Attempting to launch and connect to Player using URL C:\Users\eivmey\Documents\practice\3.0.swf
[SWF] C:\Users\eivmey\Documents\It 2\fly\3.0.swf - 475976 bytes after decompression

USA
Australia
* Infinite spam of Australia follows

__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_--

EDIT: Solved it

Ok, the problem was in the flyplass class.

```
package 
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.SimpleButton;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFormat;

public class flyplass extends Main()
{
        // variables 
        public function flyplass(input1, input2)
        {
            // code
        }
```

When changing `extends Main()` to `extends MovieClip` it suddenly worked. Do you know why?

Comment: try debug your movie (ctrl+shift+enter) instead of running it(ctrl+enter), you will have more information about the error and where it occurs.

Comment: thank you - didn't know about that feature. I will edit the question and add the output it gave.

Comment: More of that you can place breakpoints on your code to stop the script on certain lines (just double click on the line number or click on the right of the line number depending of flash version). You can try commenting some lines too to see which code cause the error.

Comment: maybe try changing the type of k to String.

Comment: changing to String did not work, unfortunately. But this is a bit weird, I used the exact same code in the timeline previously, and then it worked fine.

Comment: The problem appears when i create a new instance of "flyplass". (norwegian for airport :) ) The variables k, key and value are all well-functioning.

Comment: in extending Main, you reenter a loop each time you create a flyplass and so on...